# Re-indexing blocks taking more than a week - Cant access my wallet

Tags: blockchain

I've bought Bitcoins and had them directed to a wallet on the Bitcoin-Qt software. Unfortunately I was not aware of the sync process. And now I've got no access to the Btc's and I feel like the syncing will never happen.

Running on Mac OS X 10.8.5
2.3 GHz Itel i7
16 GB Memory

Running Bitcoin v0.8.5

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly import your wallet to blockchain.info, which will give you instant access to your funds. From there you can send them back to a usable wallet on your Mac, such as Electrum or MultiBit which don't require lengthy synchronisation times. I do not recommend you leave your funds in a web-based wallet like Blockchain.info's for longer than you need to, but they are generally regarded as being trustworthy.

Find your `wallet.dat` in `/Users/<name>/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`, and follow the instructions on the page below.

https://blockchain.info/wallet/import-wallet

Some alternative, fast syncing Mac clients.

http://electrum.org/

https://multibit.org/

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and quick reply. It worked very easily. I've heard good things about electrum. Much appreciation for taking the time to help :)

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to back your seed properly, and you'll never be at risk of losing your coins.